# Highcharts - How do I get dashed lines in legend

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using a basic line graph with some of the data series having dashed lines.

```
{
   name: 'Country Population',
   data: [1, 2, 3, 4], dashStyle: 'longdash'
}
```

However I can't get the legend to reflect which lines have dashes. Ideally I want the legend to include which lines have the dashes?

http://jsfiddle.net/cbx3r91u/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `symbolWidth` to make the lines large enough to see the dashes.

```
symbolWidth: 40
```

seems to work well.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbx3r91u/1/)