# How to make - - legend in 'areaspline' type high charts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, angular-highcharts

I already had look at [Highcharts - How do I get dashed lines in legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31384157/highcharts-how-do-i-get-dashed-lines-in-legend) . Its for "line" chart type my chart type is "areaspline" where I need dashed style legend "-- Legend" even below code `events: {load: function(event) {$('.highcharts-legend-item rect').attr('height', '2').attr('y', '10');}}` could bring '-'line legend but I am in need of "--"
here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/manjula_dhamodharan/4tejg3v6/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create mocked `line` series and link `areaspline` ones to them. Example:

```
  series: [{
    name: 'Tokyo',
    dashStyle: 'longdash',
    type: 'line',
    id: 'line1'
  }, {
    name: 'London',
    dashStyle: 'longdash',
    type: 'line',
    id: 'line2'
  }, {
    linkedTo: 'line1',
    name: 'Tokyo',
    ...

  }, {
    linkedTo: 'line2',
    name: 'London',
    ...
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/815vctmr/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.linkedTo